# How to send data to server within a jquery load callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use the following code to call an external html file and load it into a defined div, like so...

```
$('app').load('projects.html',loadProjects);
```

Then within the callback function, I execute an ajax to post data to server and await for a response, like so...

```
function loadProjects(){
    $.ajax({
       method: 'post',
       url: 'functions/saveproject.php',
       data: ...
       success: function(result){
          console.log(result);
       }
    });
}
```

In saveproject.php, the code returns a success result, like so...

```
<?php
   echo "success"
?>
```

The problem is console.log(result) shows the whole code of the saveproject.php as text instead of the expected echoed value "success".

What am I doing wrong? Is doing an ajax call inside a callback function of a jquery load making this unexpected result? If so, how can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: You need to specify `dataType: "json"` in your `$.ajax`

Comment: @Milan Hi! whether I specify dataType = "json" or dataType = "text", both echoes the php data as text, meaning it just outputs the whole php file as text.

Comment: you probably need to check if PHP is installed .. I am sure, PHP isn't installed and hence it will show everything as text..